# Angular 5 loading locale at runtime with Angular CLI

Tags: angular, typescript, localization, angular-cli, angular5

Angular 5 provides a way to load i18n locale at runtime using *registerLocaleData*

https://angular.io/guide/i18n#i18n-pipes

I would like to load the locale dynamically based on a setting (for example stored in localStorage). My first test was to load a single locale (fr):

```
import(`@angular/common/locales/fr`).then(locale => {
    registerLocaleData(locale.default);
});
```

This works fine.

When loading based on a value stored in localStorage, like this:

```
const localeName = localStorage.getItem('locale') || 'en';

import(`@angular/common/locales/${localeName}`).then(locale => {
    registerLocaleData(locale.default);
});
```

It also works, and the locale is loaded successfully. When bulding the project using Angular CLI, since at build time it doesn't know which locale to bundle, it bundles all of them, which is fine. The only issue is that the build process gives a warning for every locale it loads:

> Module build failed: Error:
>   node_modules\@angular\common\locales\af-NA.d.ts is not part of the
>   compilation output. Please check the other error messages for details.
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/common/locales/af-NA.js.map
>   Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:10)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

I already tried to include the locale *.ts files and exclude *.map files but it doesn't seem to pick them up.

This is my *tsconfig.app.json*:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "esnext",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "../node_modules/@angular/common/locales/**/*.map"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*",
    "../node_modules/@angular/common/locales/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

TypeScript needs *esnext* as module to make the dynamic import work. With es2015 it doesn't work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Importing only the *.js files seems to fix the issue, like this:

```
import(`@angular/common/locales/${localeName}.js`).then(locale => {
   registerLocaleData(locale.default); 
});
```

No need to include or exclude files in *tsconfig.app.json*

Comment: How can you make sure to load the right localeName? If I use navigator.language when it's set to en-US for example, there is no corresponding js file ... (the name is "en-US-POSIX.js")

Comment: There is no `en-US` because it is the same as `en`. I think the reason is described here https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20340#issuecomment-343865420

This solution was implemented for Angular 4, maybe in a newer version there is a safer way to achieve the same thing. If you find a solution for this, please share.

Comment: does the import fail, can you catch the error in a `catch` or `error` handler? a workaround might be to do something like this (not sure if the code runs and ideally the import part should be a separate function instead of duplicating): 
```ts
import(`@angular/common/locales/${localeName}.js`).then(locale => {
   registerLocaleData(locale.default); 
}).error(() => {
   const baseLocale = 'en'; // extract the first part from the locale (i.e.'en' from 'en-US')
   import(`@angular/common/locales/${baseLocale}.js`).then(locale => {
        registerLocaleData(locale.default); 
}
});

```

Comment: Thanks for the update. What is the variable localeName set in the first place?

Comment: the value for `localeName` is retrieved from an API, it is the locale associated with the authenticated user. by default it is `en`