# How to import from locales dynamically?

Tags: angular

I'm building an Angular 5 app. My users can choose any culture they want in my app. Should I really put the "locales" path hardcoded? if so I should include them all (just in case).

```
import localeFr from '@angular/common/locales/fr';
registerLocaleData(localeFr, 'fr');
import localePt from '@angular/common/locales/pt';
registerLocaleData(localePt, 'pt');
...
```

I want something like this :

```
import locale from '@angular/common/locales/' + varUserLocale;
registerLocaleData(locale);
```

How can I make it a bit more dynamic like my example?

Thanks

Comment: Still haven't found a clean way to do this?

Comment: @JonathP : nope, still importing everything...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

import(`@angular/common/locales/${navigator.language}.js`).then(locale => {
  registerLocaleData(locale.default);
});

Source: [Angular 5 loading locale at runtime with Angular CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47484292/angular-5-loading-locale-at-runtime-with-angular-cli)

Comment: The link itself is not considered a good answer. This should be comment not the answer.

Comment: Hello @Hugo Caldeira, Sorry it not correctly interpreded by Angular : 
[ts] The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type.
[tslint] unused expression, expected an assignment or function call (no-unused-expression)

Answer (score 1):

```
export interface ILanguageOption {
  languageId: number;
  name: string;
  value: string;
  priority: number;
  import: string;
}

  public static readonly LANGUAGES: ILanguageOption[] = [
    { languageId: 2, name: 'RU', value: 'ru-RU', priority: 2, import: 'ru' },
    { languageId: 1, name: 'EN', value: 'en-UK', priority: 1, import: 'en-GB' }
  ];
```

in app.modele.ts

```
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';

export function localeInitializerFactory(): () => Promise<any> {
  return () => {
    const all = Consts.LANGUAGES.map(l => {
      Promise.all([
        import(/* webpackInclude: /(ru|en-GB)\.js$/ */ `@angular/common/locales/${l.import}.js`),
        import(/* webpackInclude: /(ru|en-GB)\.js$/ */ `@angular/common/locales/extra/${l.import}.js`)
      ]).then(imp => registerLocaleData(imp[0].default, l.value, imp[1].default));
    });
    return Promise.all(all);
  }
}

{
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: localeInitializerFactory,
  multi: true
},
```